# ReactJS not updating state google map autocomplete fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, google-places-autocomplete, google-map-place

I have integrated google map auto-completed, it's working well, even i have `console` logged, every data is appearing as expected but the problem is, when i select, it doesn't update the `state`

Here you go for my component

```
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";

const TestForm = () => {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

    const onPlaceSelected = (place) => {
      console.log(place)
      setProfile({...profile, "test": "test"})
      console.log(profile, )
    };

    const handleProfileChange = (e) => {
        setProfile({...profile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
      };

  
  return (
    <>
      
    <input onChange={handleProfileChange} type="text"></input>

    <Autocomplete
        apiKey="apikey"
        defaultValue={formData.profile.location || ""}
        onPlaceSelected={onPlaceSelected}
        />
                            
    </>
  );
};
```

You may notice, i used two different method to update state, one for general input fields and another for `autocomplete` lib, but general `input` field state is updateing but `autocomplete` state is not updating, i have console logged the `place`, i see it is appearing, only problem is when i select a location, the selected location doesnt add my state, what is the issue? why it's behaving so weirds? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You cant log the state right after you updated it, because it's async. Try logging the state change in useEffect hook

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

const onPlaceSelected = (place) => {
  console.log(place)
  setProfile({...profile, "test": "test"})
};

useEffect(() => { console.log(profile) }, [profile])
```

Comment: Hey, it works but other state is being reset now,

Comment: It's because `onPlaceSelected` overwrites, the state right after `onPlaceSelected`, with the old state, when you do `{ ...profile }` which does not contain changes from `onPlaceSelected` state change. I would suggest keep two separate states, and if you need - handle them with useEffect